# On the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, Where do I plug the Energenie module?

Tags: gpio, pi-2

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.
The GPIO pins look exactly like this:

[image]

I bought the Energenie Raspberry Pi RF-Transmitter Board.
The instructions (https://energenie4u.co.uk/res/pdfs/ENER314%20UM.pdf) show where the board should be plugged in a different model Raspberry Pi.

[image]

So there are several potential places I can connect the Energenie board.
Does it go

- All the way to the left?
- All the way to the right?
- Does it line up with that "GPIO" which seems to start at the fourth set of pins from the left?
- Or somewhere else?

If someone could take that top image and draw a box around the correct pin placement in Paint or something that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All the way to the left?

This one (pins 1-26 are common)
I found this fine picture: [image: Pi pinout]

Answer (score 2):

all the way to the right (towards the SD card). The first 26 pins on the 26 pin and 40 pin Pi's are the same.

You may have a problem getting it to fit because of the extra pins. You have a couple of options in that case.

- cutting pins 27+28 (the fourteeth row),
- trimming the header to clear the extra pins (not recommended as it may effect the integrity of the mechanical or electrical connection),
- [female to male jumper wires](https://www.adafruit.com/products/826),
- [stacking headers](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1979) (which you can remove the interfering pins without damaging the Pi),
- an [adapter board](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Raspberry-Pi-AB2-40pin-to-26pin-GPIO-Board-p-2190.html),
- a [breadboard breakout board](http://www.adafruit.com/products/914?gclid=Cj0KEQiAg7ayBRD8qqSGt-fj6uYBEiQAucjOwT_GxNL-Y2OFfS2loUSTFRrDZ4o80Gc8bwMJ1Kn_UAQaAtuI8P8HAQ).

Comment: Thanks! It fitted perfectly without the others getting in the way, it just slotted in no problems at all. Initially I was confused but I think left/right is just a perspective thing. It's all the way down towards the SD card so your answer is the same as the other one (who said the left), sorry, should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: No problem I said right based on the pic (and added toward the SD card to be clear). Honestly I think the confusion came from the Pic in the other answer is flipped around to a different perspective.